# Required character in NSString is replaced with encoded variable

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode5

I have an NSString that contains a value "\U2212" instead of "-" which is coming from API. When I tried to replace this string with needed character using subString occurrence method it shown error. So how do I replace my NSString that contains "\U2212" with "-". I tried the following code. Please help me. I searched many things but nothing helped. Thanks in advance.

input:"(UTC\U221206:00) Canada/Central"

Desired output:"(UTC-06:00) Canada/Central"

code:

```
NSString *timezoneDisplayValue = [timezone valueForKey:@"tomeZoneDisplayValue"];
timezoneDisplayValue = [timezoneDisplayValue stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\U2212" withString:@"-"];
```

Comment: `\U2212` ? `\\U2212`? `\U0002212`?

Comment: What are the bets that you are misinterpreting the output of an NSLog statement? U2212 is a Unicode "minus sign". What makes you think you need to replace it?

Comment: my Api is returning like that. So I need to replace this with -

Comment: Are you sure that the string is holding "\U2212" before replacing it. I would assume it is holding "\\U2212" before replacing. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

below code returns YES or NO, whether your string has any encoding...

```
[apiString canBeConvertedToEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

If NO is returned, then convert with the correct encoding type :

```
[apiString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF16BigEndianStringEncoding];
```

Comment: But the second line is applicable for NSData right? If I am wrong please show me how to use it. Thankyou.